# RASA - rasa run actions - localhost issues

Tags: python, rasa-core, rasa

I am learning Rasa using the RASA masterclass youtube channel. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJ0V6493mLvqdiVwOKWBODQ

It has all worked until it has come to loading actions. Each time I use rasa run actions in the command prompt (the first of the two actions) the program gets stuck and I have to manually kill it. When I use rasa shell --endpoints endpoints.yml, bot works however as I keep encountering when I add in a custom action the server returns cannot connect to localhost like in the bottom example. The question is how to I get passed this issue.

*Please ask for additional info

:[image]

my actions.py looks like the below:

```
from typing import Any, Text, Dict, List

from rasa_sdk import Action, Tracker
from rasa_sdk.executor import CollectingDispatcher
from rasa_sdk.events import SlotSet



class ActionFacilitySearch(Action):

    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_facility_search"

    def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
            tracker: Tracker,
            domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

        facility = tracker.get_slot("facility_type")
        address = "300 Hyde St, San Francisco"
        dispatcher.utter_message("Here is the address of the {}:{}".format(facility, address))

        return []
```

in domain.yml, for the actions section I have;

```
actions:
- utter_greet
- utter_cheer_up
- utter_did_that_help
- utter_happy
- utter_goodbye
- utter_iamabot
- utter_ask_location
- action_facility_search
```

and in endpoints.yml, most is #'d out but the active bit is:

```
action_endpoint:
  url: "http://localhost:9000/webhook"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very simple answer in the end. I needed to run two commands windows. The first one for:

```
rasa run actions
```

Then a second window for either:

```
rasa x
```

or

```
rasa shell
```

this then worked as it should.

Answer (score 2):

Please do not change endpoints.yml with any other port for action_endpoint

Please check with 5055 port it was working perfectly.

```
action_endpoint:
  url: "http://localhost:5055/webhook"
```

Your action server running on 5055 port. if you want it to set 9000 then change it from rasa core backend request.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your custome actions server couldn't able to connect with the endpoint server which is mentioned in endpoints.yml

While running actions.py provide the port number as rasa run actions -p portnumber

Make sure the port number you give here is mentioned in endpoints.yml

Answer (score 0):

I solve by using the following commands

```
rasa run actions
```

Then a second window for either:

```
rasa x
```

this then worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the given image, I am assuming that you want to run the action server on port 9000. 
If you do want to run action server on port 9000, then you need to make these changes:

endpoints.yml:

```
action_endpoint:
  url: "http://localhost:9000/webhook"
```

Command to run action server:

```
rasa run actions -p 9000 --debug
```

user `--debug` option too check is there issue in action file.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal 1 run

```
rasa actions
```

In terminal 2 run
Check you have the model inplace inside the models folder if it is not there use

```
rasa train
```

Then run

```
rasa shell --endpoints endpoints.yml
```